# Stored procedure to bulk import Excel sheet data into SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

```
alter procedure _sp_ImportExcelFile            
            (@Source varchar(1000)
            , @SourceSheet varchar (100)
            , @DestinationTable varchar (100))
as
   declare @retval int

   EXEC master..xp_fileexist @Source, @retval output -- check if file exists

   if @retval = 0
            begin
                        print 'file does not exist.'
                        return
            end

   if @SourceSheet is null or @SourceSheet = ''
            set @SourceSheet = '[projects_export$]' 
   else
            set @SourceSheet = '[' + ltrim(rtrim(@SourceSheet)) + '$]'

   if @DestinationTable is null or @DestinationTable = ''
            set @DestinationTable = substring(@SourceSheet, 2, len(@SourceSheet) - 3) + convert(varchar, getdate(), 126)

   exec('select * into [' + @DestinationTable + '] from openrowset
(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'', ''Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=' + @Source + ''', ' + 
@SourceSheet + ')')
```

and I am using this as execute statement

```
exec _sp_ImportExcelFile 'D:\exceldata\','projects_export','ExcelData'
```

where `projects_export` is the name of the sheet and `ExcelData` is the name of my table
but get the error as `file doesn't exist`

Comment: At least format your code before posting.

Comment: shouldn't you be passing the exact excel file name while calling the proc like `exec _sp_ImportExcelFile 'D:\exceldata\test.xls','projects_export','ExcelData'`

Comment: have done that too still the same

Comment: error you are getting itself self explanatory. Check whether the filename and path you are specifying is correct?

Comment: file is there but didn't get the output so I asked the question whether it is actually the error it is saying or something else logical error is the stored procedure or I am not getting the proper way of passing the parameter in execute statement

Comment: Can you show the contents of `master..xp_fileexist`?